# What does =+ mean in (T)SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I found something like this in a SqlServer DB stored proc:

```
SELECT stuff
  FROM mytable
 WHERE mytable.column = + @parameter
```

It seems to run without error, so I assume it's okay.  What would the "+" be doing?

(Not surprisingly, this is a difficult topic to effectively search on, so I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate.)

Comment: Remove the +, it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unary `+` doesn't do anything in T-SQL.

Perhaps the person who wrote it saw `0+@parameter` and deleted the `0` to "optimize it". `0+@parameter` generates an error if `@parameter` isn't numeric, whereas unary `+` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 5):

`+` is the opposite of `-` which changes sign.

It does nothing.

Comment: if @paramater is an unsigned tinyint it would cast it to a smallint. I have the link from MS in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What type is `@parameter`?  This probably just a unary plus, (as opposed to minus).  For numeric types this has no effect.

Comment: It's a char(20)...but it is holding, in every case I can see, an integer value...so maybe it's just auto-casting it, and allowing the unary plus.

Answer (score 1):

> Returns the data type of
>   numeric_expression, except that an
>   unsigned tinyint expression is
>   promoted to a smallint result.

[Positive unary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276855%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a short hand notation for converting the parameter into a numeric type. Depending on your database server, it might not even be needed.